# PHP check get request for string after its been encoded

Tags: php, urlencode

I need to replicate the method of converting `&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;` into `Â Â &gt;Â Â`.

I have a constant defined which is used as the separator between a child and parent category.

`define('CATEGORY_SEPERATOR', '&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;')` // (constant may vary)

`$sql .= "GROUP_CONCAT(c.name ORDER BY c.level SEPARATOR "'" . CATEGORY_SEPERATOR ."'") AS name`

A possible result could be

`row = array(
    'name => category1&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;category2
)`

The categories are then displayed as a list of links

`<li><a href="www.example.com/categories?&name=<?php echo $row['name'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></a></li>`

when a link is clicked the URLS are encoded.

addressbar: `www.example.com/categories?name=category1  >  category2

I want to be able to check whether the `CATEGORY_SEPERATOR` exists within `$_GET['name']` . so I can perform

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$categories = explode(CATEGORY_SEPERATOR, $name);
```

but by the time `$_GET['name']` reaches my script its beet transformed.

`$_GET['name']` *initial value*

var_dump : `string 'category1Â Â >Â Â category2' (length=27)`

*After `stripslashes()`* (no change)

var_dump : `string 'category1Â Â >Â Â category2' (length=27)`

*After* `htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');`

var_dump : `string 'category1Â Â &gt;Â Â category2' (length=30)`

Now i've managed to reverse it slightly by doing the following

`$_GET['name'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($_GET['name'], ENT_COMPAT);`

`if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')){
    $_GET['name'] = addcslashes($_GET['name']);
}`

But still need to get it from

`category1Â Â >Â Â category2` to `&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

Ive tried using urldeocde and rawurldecode, without any luck.

Comment: You're complaining about the `Â `? That's a character set issue. Your text is corrupted, and you'll need to fix it all - there's no 100% reliable method to detect what really SHOULD be `Â` and what's a mangled charcter. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Thanks, I thought that some how `Â ` was an encoded version of `&nbsp;`. thanks for the link

Comment: `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space. it'd never show up as `Â`, since it's by definition a space character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reversing the process used to encode will work but unfortunately somewhere on the client side(browser) the data is being changed/corrupted before it is sent to the server.

These are a list of the functions with there counterpart.

- [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) -> [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)
- [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) -> [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)
- [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) -> [addcslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)